# I am designing a Linked List where I can Insert and delete item from the list. But there is an issue inserting item at the end of linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am designing a Linked List where I can Insert and delete item from the list. But there is an issue inserting item at the end of linked list.

I thought my logic was fine for inserting an item at the end of linked list. But I am getting this (segmentation fault : core dumped) error when I am trying to insert item that should be inserted at the end of Linked List. Can Anyone help me with this issue

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct list
{
    int data;
    list *next,*back;
};

typedef struct list node;

node *start = NULL;

void display()
{
    node *temp;
    temp = start;

    while (temp!=NULL)
    {
        cout << temp->data << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void insertion(int item)
{
    node *temp,*temp2;

    if(start == NULL)
    {
        start = new node();
        start->data = item;
        start->next = NULL;
    }

    else if(item <= start->data)
    {
        temp = new node();
        temp->data = item;
        temp->next = start;
        start = temp;
    }
    else // this the logic for inserting middle and end of linked list
    {
        temp = start;

        while(item >= temp->next->data && temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        temp2 = new node();
        temp2->data = item;
        temp2->next = temp->next;
        temp->next = temp2;
    }
}

void deletion()
{

}

void showMenu()
{
    cout << "0.Exit\n1.ShowMenu\n2.Insert\n3.Delete\n4.Display" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    showMenu();
    int choice;
    cout <<"Enter your Choice " << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    while(choice != 0)
    {
        if(choice == 1)
        {
            showMenu();
        }
        else if(choice == 2)
        {
            int item;
            cout << "Enter your item " << endl;
            cin >> item;
            insertion(item);
        }
        else if(choice == 3)
        {
            deletion();
        }
        else if(choice == 4)
        {
            display();
        }
        else
        {
            choice = 0;
        }

        cout <<"Enter your Choice " << endl;
        cin >> choice;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is `temp->next` in `temp2->next = temp->next;`initialized `NULL` to insert at the end? C, but you may find inspiration in [Singly Linked List (node only, no wrapper)](https://pastebin.com/5MPLU4wB) for using both the address of pointer and pointer to node to simplify insertion (if you are not using C++ references). Then see [Singly Linked List of Integers (example)](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A) for using both `head` and `tail` pointers for O(n) insertion at the end.

Comment: I'd recommend a C++-style linked list if you're going to tag C++.

Comment: What is `back` for?  If this is a doubly-linked list, consider using a more appropriate name like `prev` (which also has symmetry with the name "next").  In C++, when we see "back", we think "end of list", which is an inappropriate thing for a list node to point at.

Comment: Why do you need a menu to demonstrate this error? For a [mre], your main function should look more like `int main() { insertion(1); insertion(2); }`, and the then-unused functions could be removed from the example.